# Contingency table

Tags: probability

I'm trying to solve a question regarding contingency table as far as I know contingency table show count not densities,and I'm having hard time comprehending this simple table.
My attempts was basically calculating the marginal distribution but the probabilities didn't sum to 1.
for example I tried solving the first question by:
$$
P(A, B) = \int(P(A,B,C)dC
$$
but I'm missing something is $dC$ probabilities or just count?

[Contingency table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IU133.png)

Comment: Well, yeah this is the given question with table on the right.

Answer (score 1):

This is discrete.  You just need to add things up, no integrals required.  For the conditional ones you have to scale by the probability of the given event.

In the one that asks for $\Pr(A,B|C=0)$, we see from that table that $\Pr(C=0)=.45$, by adding up all the entries with $C=0$.  We also know that $\Pr(A=1,B=1,C=0)=.05$.  In the new contingency table, the entry for $A=1,B=1$ will be $\frac{.05}{.45}=\frac19$.  The values in the table always have to add up to $1$.

Comment: Ok, if we sum the $C$ column we will get 4 and thus $0.01*4=0.04...$ and by doing so for the rest of the rows the probabilities won't sum to 1, since it was multiplied by 4.

Comment: No, you sum the probabilities.

Comment: I see, can you please suggest some resources or a book chapter to read about this more?

Comment: I don't know anything about these contingency tables per se, but this is just elementary probability theory.  Any book or website that discusses conditional probability will explain it.